# NSURLConnectionLoader & tcpConnWorkQueue triggering crash

Tags: objective-c, macos, crash, nsurlconnection, crash-reports

For only one single user, out of about 100 people as far as I'm aware, our app is randomly crashing. The stack traces don't show any methods/functions from my app (com.mgs.TAT) being in the thread that triggers the crash. Is something external killing my app?

The crash reports always show 1 of two causes. Either:

```
Crashed Thread:  6  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000028
```

or

```
Crashed Thread:  2  Dispatch queue: tcpConnWorkQueue

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000e7b7c8c0
```

Does anybody have any ideas for troubleshooting this further to narrow down the issue?

I've made pastebins of two crash reports, one for each scenario:

1. [com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader](http://pastebin.com/SviHxxjU)
2. [Dispatch queue: tcpConnWorkQueue](http://pastebin.com/Y7SPYrMP)

The user was previously on 10.9.4, but upgraded to the later version of OS X. That made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like both of these crashes are related to clearing out the request headers.

So start there — see if there's anything weird happening with your header fields & values.

For example, you might be calling `-release` or `CFRelease` on an auto-released object.

Comment: I'm adding custom HTTP headers in one place. I'll check that, thanks for the suggestion. Out of curiosity, what part gave you the ideas it may be related to request headers?